# Pull Up New Input Box In VBA UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am looking to pull up a new input box based on certain information from my userform. My current way of doing this is by having it pull up a new userform but that makes me redefine all of my variables and seems clunky.

```
If yesval = "no" Then
     NewAcctDescrip.Show
End If
```

In the NewAcctDesrip form:

```
Cells(subtotrow, descripcol).Value = NewAcctDescrip.NADText.Value
```

Is there a way to just get an immediate prompt that I can use?

SOLVED:

```
variable = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Information?")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use [Application.InputBox()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx) function

Comment: @user3598756 or the host-agnostic `VBA.Interaction.InputBox` function from the standard library. `Application.InputBox` is a creature of Excel ;-)

Comment: &Mat'sMug, I named Application since OP's tags. But I didn't know VBA.Interaction class at all. Nice to know that. Thank you!